# How to bypass lack of layouts and JPanel in C# (WinfForms)

Tags: c#, java, winforms, layout

Question: How to achieve it in C#(WinForms)?

EDIT1: I use Visual Studio 2013 but I do not want use any designers just plain code.

EDIT2: In the example below panels and buttons resize themselves to fit the Panels.

I am creating a `UserControl`(WinForms) which instances will be resized a lot and I do not want that buttons in this `UserControl` will be invisible when the size will change.

In the main `UserControl` are going to be 2 `UserControls` one at the center and one at the bottom containing 2 `Buttons`(screen shot of that idea written in Java below).

In Java I would write:

```
public class LayoutDemo extends JFrame {
JPanel centerPanel, lowerPanel;
    public LayoutDemo(){
        super();
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        setSize(400,400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 4));

        lowerPanel = new JPanel();
        lowerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 4));
        lowerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        lowerPanel.add(new JButton("PLAY"));
        lowerPanel.add(new JButton("STOP"));

        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {     
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayoutDemo().createGUI();           
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The result is that no matter what compoments "know their place" and they resize themselves automatically.

[image]
[image]

**But how to achieve it in C#?**

Comment: Are you using a designer. If so, which one (Visual Studio, etc.)?

Comment: I use VS2013 but I do not want to use any drag&drop designer. Just code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button panel, set Dock to Bottom; on the other Panel, set Dock = Fill (be careful, the order that things are created/set gets involved). That ensures that they stay where they are. Then set Anchor on top panel to Top, Left, Right, Bottom, and on the button panel to Left and Right. That will take care of resizing.

Comment: Ok but how to insert UserControl in the UserControl I do not have one in my toolbox

Comment: Well if you're doing it all in code, then just create it and place it in code.. Otherwise IIRC (it's a long time since I last did a UserControl), drag it from the Solution Explorer and drop it on the form. To add it to the Toolbox, right-click on the toolbox, take 'Select Items' and browse for the dll which contains the UserControls.

Comment: Ok I used the toolbox and anchoring and docking did a good job... almost for example in the `GridLayou` -->image above the buttons are automatically resized to fill all the `lowerPanel`. Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Not quite as easy. Anchor the left one to the left and the right to the right. That's the easy part. In the UserControl Resize event, set both button's widths to 1/2 the Panel width. That's all I can think of, I'm afraid. It might be worth setting up another question asking exactly this as it's a while since I did this stuff and might have forgotten.

Comment: In the `UserControl_Resize` event, put the following code: `ButtonPlay.Width = lowerPanel.Width / 2;` and `ButtonStop.Width = lowerPanel.Width / 2;`